# How to get php-native handle from Doctrine\DBAL\Connection?

Tags: php, mysqli, doctrine

Given the code

```
$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => $this->dbname,
    'user' => $this->dbuser,
    'password' => $this->dbpass,
    'host' => $this->dbhost,
    'driver' => 'mysqli',
);

$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams);        
var_dump($conn);
```

How can I get the underlying mysqli handle from $conn (which is a Doctrine\DBAL\Connection)?

I have found **a way** to access it, but its obviously not the way it's supposed to be done, so I'm up for suggestions:

```php
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams);        
foreach((array)$conn->getWrappedConnection() as $mysqli){
    // TODO: find official way of getting the handle.
    // here we are casting it to (array) to access its PRIVATE PROPERTIES
    // it's a fugly hack. 
    break;
}
var_dump($mysqli);
```

Comment: What does `$conn->getWrappedConnection()` return?

Comment: @Dharman it returns `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\Connection` , whatever that is

Comment: Right, and then what are its properties? Isn't there one called `mysqli` or `conn`?

Comment: @Dharman it has a *private* property called `conn` which contains the mysqli handle, it has 0 public properties :( it has 8 public methods, but none of them returns anything relevant as far as i can see (beingTransaction, commit, exec, lastInsertId, prepare, query, quote, and rollBack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it this way:

```
$mysqli = $conn->getWrappedConnection()->getWrappedResourceHandle();
```

Comment: thanks! strangely the getWrappedResourceHandle() is not part of the interface Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection , which is where i looked for its methods, and i used var_dump() to see its properties, so i missed it